# Add events to ListView's inflated RowViews in Activity or Adapter class?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having trouble iterating over my inflated custom `RowView` in the `ListView` of my Activity class and assigning the proper events to controls on the inflated custom `RowView`.

Yes, I can add events to the controls in the Adapter class `GetView()` override, but I think there are a couple problems with that.

1. I'm under the impression all application logic should live in the
   Activity class and the adapter should just be used for data binding. If I add all the navigation logic, CRUD operations, etc, to the controls in the Adpater nothing would live in the activity and the Adapter would now be responsible for application logic, event handling, database helper class interaction, etc.
2. I don't have access to `StartActivity()` or `this` in the Adapter
   class, so the Adapter doesn't seem be the place to add navigation logic,
   e.g. I want a button on the row to open the "Detail View", but can't if I
   cannot call `StartActivity()` or pass in the proper parameters to
   `Intent()`.

So, I thought I'd just add the events to the controls in the Activity class. Next problem, in the activity class, I cannot figure out how to iterate over the `ListView` items, e.g. there is no `ListView.Items` collection to iterate over and add the event handlers to the various controls.

I've been walking through several Pluralsight courses and examples elsewhere and typically those have just had event handlers on the `ListView_ItemClick`, which is added in the Activity class. That's simple enough and I have that implemented and working, but I'm unable to achieve the same for the controls on the inflated custom `RowView`

Is there a way to iterate over the inflated custom `RowViews` of a `ListView`? Am I mistaken about what code should live in the Activity vs Adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Implement the `View.IOnClickListener` interface in your adapter
2. add this in your adapter

   ```
   private InnerItemOnclickListener mListener;

   public interface InnerItemOnclickListener
   {
       void itemClick(View v);
   }

   public void SetOnInnerItemOnClickListener(InnerItemOnclickListener listener)
   {
       this.mListener = listener;
   }

   public void OnClick(View v)
   {
       mListener.itemClick(v);
   }
   ```

3.in your adpater's BindData() method ,add this:

```
deleteName.SetOnClickListener(this);

editName.SetOnClickListener(this);
```

4.in your activity,implement the `BabyNameListAdapter.InnerItemOnclickListener` and `AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener` interface

5.add this in your activity:

```
private BabyNameListAdapter Adapter;
public void itemClick(View v)
    {
        int position;
        position = (int)v.Tag;
        switch (v.Id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.editNameButton:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("editNameButton click"+" position="+position);
                break;
            case Resource.Id.deleteNameButton:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("deleteNameButton click" + " position=" + position);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("RowView click");
    }
```

6.replace your `BindData()` with this:

```
private void BindData()

{

    Adapter = new BabyNameListAdapter(this, allBabyNames);

    Adapter.SetOnInnerItemOnClickListener(this);

    babyNameListView.Adapter=Adapter;


}
```

7.replace `babyNameListView.ItemClick += BabyNameListView_ItemClick;` with `babyNameListView.OnItemClickListener = this;`

8.run your project.

- Ok,now you can click your listview's rowview and the button on the rowview, and it will work well.
- You can see that I use the interface to set the click event not in adapter but in activity. There is no clear boundaries where to write you logic code , only one thing which need to care is the performence .
- You of course can use `startActivity()` in your adapter if you want to pass the parameters to your adapter ,but it will complex ,so use interface you can handler this in your activity.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry for the delay in getting back, I was busy with the holiday. I implemented your suggested solution, which worked. However, I have a couple questions that you might be able to assist with. First, the `ItemClick(View v)` logic seems like it's a violation of OCP because I'd have to modify multiple classes if I ever wanted to add/remove a control, e.g. add to adapter class, add to activity case statement, etc. Is this really how my situation is best handled in Xamarin/Android? It seems like the `ItemClick(View v)` logic has a "bad smell"

Comment: Second, I couldn't add the rowview instance itself to the case statement because there is no `Resource.Id.babyNameRowView`, so I threw the OnClick logic into the default branch of the switch, which worked, but is there a way to reference the instance for the case statement?

Comment: Regardless, this gives me something good to work with, I appreciate the help. I will mark as the answer later this evening, but I wanted to have a chance to discuss my comments. Thanks again.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but if you could please respond to my comments, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: About your first question, I use the `InnerItemOnclickListener` interface to change the click event control from `BabyNameListAdapter` to `BabyNameExplorerActivity` , so if you add/remove a control ,you need change the two classes .

Comment: Second ,if you want to get the rowview instance, look up the
 `AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener` I have implemented , in `OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)` you can get the instance. `Resource.Id.babyNameRowView` is a ID of rowview's layout, it will reuse in `listview` . You can use `babyNameListView.GetChildAt` to get every rowview instance